# Debian: get the login name from UID

Tags: linux, debian, user-accounts

What I need is something like:

```
$ who-has-uid 1000
cyrus
```

I know the file `/etc/passwd` contains such informations, I'm not asking a script that parses it.

Comment: Why not? Sounds like the easiest solution if you have read access to that file...

Comment: Because I can't believe there isn't such built-in tool in Debian (e.g. `id -u cyrus` just do the opposite thing).

Comment: Simple enough to do in a one line bash function:
who-has-uid()
{
grep $1 /etc/passwd| awk -F: '{print $1;}'
}

Comment: `who-has-uid 100` will match also `100`, `1001`, ... I would use `getent passwd 100 | cut -f1 -d:` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have root access, it's as simple as:

```
sudo -u \#${pid} whoami
```

Comment: Finally! Thanks, I meant something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [getent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getent) ([getent man page](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/getent.1.php)):

```
$ getent passwd 1005
shufler:x:1005:119:shufler,,,:/home/local/shufler:/bin/bash
```

You could parse out just the username with sed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ who-has-uid() { perl -e 'print +(getpwuid('$1'))[0], "\n"'; }
$ who-has-uid 0
root
$ who-has-uid 1
daemon
```

Note that this will work (assuming Perl is configured properly) even if the information comes from somewhere other than the `/etc/passwd` file.

There's no real error checking; `who-has-uid 999` prints an empty line if there's no such UID on the system.

If you don't insist on a one-liner, you can put this somewhere in your `$PATH`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $ok = 1;
foreach my $uid (@ARGV) {
    my @pw = getpwuid $uid;
    if (@pw) {
        print "$pw[0]\n";
    }
    else {
        warn "$uid: No such user\n";
        $ok = 0;
    }
}

exit 1 if not $ok;
```

Comment: Thanks but way too complicated outside a Perl context.

Comment: @cYrus: Perhaps, but you only have to write it (or copy-and-paste it from here) once.

Comment: Sure, I understand your point. With "complicated" I mean: *unnecessarily* complicated. The [accepted answer](http://superuser.com/a/363260/46005) is an example.

Comment: @cYrus: I would say that a simple `getpwuid()` or `getent`, which is available to all users, is *much less complicated* than executing a program as the target user via a privileged tool.

Comment: @grawity: _much less complicated_ is quite subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Use awk, (usually installed GNU awk, gawk)
Tell it to use colon as a delimiter, see if field 3 (the UID) is 1000, then print the first field (username)

```
gawk -F: '$3 == 1000{print $1}' < /etc/passwd
```

This is if the info is in /etc/passwd, if you have network login info (e.g. on NIS or LDAP) getent works better

```
getent passwd | gawk -F: '$3 == 1000{print $1}'
```

You **do** need single quotes: if you use double quotes, bash will try to figure out what $1 means to the shell, and not pass it to gawk.

Comment: This works, but is awfully inefficient with centralized user directories: with 500 users, it'd have to make 499 unnecessary lookups. And that's even assuming the directory supports/allows enumeration, which not all do.